# Network Device Status Monitor returning errors

Tags: powershell, networking, monitoring

I downloaded a powershell script from TechNet, but it's not working as I expected within my network.

I've confirmed that the device on my csv file list is pingable, and that the csv file is in the correct format. I've added a link to the PS script below.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Network-Device-Status-088f7b00#content

Powershell is throwing an error stating that 'Import-Csv -Path $DeviceFile' is not a recognized cmdlet. Along with this is an error stating that the argument 'ComputerName' cannot be validated. 
I would appreciate if anyone could offer some insight as to where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Can you see if this returns anything on your PowerShell console: `Get-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`

Comment: It doesn't return anything

Comment: What version of powershell are you running? Run this to get that: $psversiontable. The above module is required for `Import-csv` to work. Try `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`.

Comment: That explains the issue. Is there anyway to manually add that module to a machine? The device I'm trying to run the script from doesn't have internet access.

Comment: I was under the impression that this module is present by default. Usually, `Import-Module` would load it to ur console. If not, you can always download elsewhere, transfer to ur machine and install it. this might help: https://www.systemcenterautomation.com/2018/03/installing-powershell-modules-on/

Comment: I'm running ps version 2.0 which should actually include the import-csv cmdlet

Comment: But PS version 2.0 doesnt automatically load those modules when called, if I am not mistaken. I believe it started doing that from PS 3. So just do this: `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`. Now `Get-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` should return something

Comment: It looks like I'm missing the module file. So it looks like I'll need to do a manual install